# Shift-c acts as Control in Outline mode

Tags: key-bindings, outline-mode

I recently started having an issue. I am unsure as to how long it has existed, but it must have occurred during the past week. Whenever I type Shift-c, Emacs does not interpret it as the character C, but rather the Control command. This acts only in the outline minor mode (regular outline mode is unaffected). I am unsure if this is a component of the mode, or a bug somewhere

Comment: Please try without your init file via emacs -Q.  If the problem goes away, bisect your init file until you isolate the problem. If the problem persists, it's because of some setting at the OS level.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with outline-minor-mode and the following line in my init.el was the culprit:

```
(setq outline-minor-mode-prefix "C-c C-o")
```

Seems like that was interpreting the first "C" as Shift-C instead of Control.

Comment: That's probably because you need to wrap `"C-c C-o"` in a call to `(kbd ...)`.

Comment: I had similar problem. Solution was to add backslash to keybinding in eg. "\C-c \C-o".